# Multiple array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I wanted to combine three arrays inside a foreach,

```
$topic = explode(',',$data->topic);
$description = explode(',',$data->description);
foreach (array_combine($topic, $description) as $topic => $description) 
{
  echo $topic;
  echo $description;
}
```

Which is working for two arrays, but I want for three arrays, because I want to pass 
`$id = explode(',',$data->id);` also in the same array which is not possible using array_combine, can anyone help by passing three arrays inside same foreach?

Comment: Why do you need to explode? May we can help improve the part before, which will avoid this multi explode/combine/loop 'thing'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ID, topic and description are all in the correct order in each comma delimited string you are supplying to the script, you could use the following to create a single array key'd by the ID:

```
$id = explode(',',$data->id);
$topic = explode(',',$data->topic);
$description = explode(',',$data->description);

foreach($id as $key=>$val)
{
    $results[$val]['topic'] = $topic[$key];
    $results[$val]['description'] = $description[$key];
}
```

Comment: Great! Please consider up-voting and accepting the answer if I was able to help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$newArray=array_merge($topic,$description,$third_array);
foreach($newArray as $key=>$value)
{
echo "$key- $value <br/>";
}
```